# Does Google Maps have the potential to do what he does MapData?

Tags: google-maps

With all the potential of the Google Maps API, you can get something done as this site:

http://www.mapdata.com.mx/productos_geoempresa.html

The question is not to know how to do, as it would take a lot of development and analysis, doubt itself is whether it has the potential to do that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No google maps is not A GIS.. for example in GIS you work by scale with google you can show the maps by zoom level (not related to fixed scale).. there are several aspect deeply different beetween what you can do with a gis but nit with google..

Another importa aspect is related to spatial/geometry operation.. these are common with gis but not available for Google..

If you need a GIS you find in google only some features but not what is tipicl for a GIS.. otherwise google give you easy georeference feauture , satellite mapping.. ruotes service and a lot of web and user mapping  oriented  features..

Comment: Thank you for your comments!